# ruby on rails: What's the equivalent statement of find_by_sql?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the equivalent rails statement of the following ?

```
@temp = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT posts.id,posts.title, comment_count.count FROM posts INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments GROUP BY post_id) AS comment_count ON comment_count.post_id = posts.id  ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;")
```

Is it possible to convert it to find/where/select statements ?

It's a complex query , i can't get it , but tried something like this,

```
@temp = Post.select("posts.id, posts.title, comment_count.count").joins(:comments).group("post_id").order("countpages.counts desc").limit(5)
```

Comment: Are you going to ask this question for every query you have? Please try to figure it out yourself first, then if you cannot figure it out, show us what you tried and someone will help you.

Comment: It's a complex query , i can't get it , but tried something like this, @temp = Post.select("posts.id, posts.title, comment_count.count").joins(:comments).group("post_id").order("countpages.counts desc").limit(5)

Comment: This is not a bad question... +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) may clean this up even further, I'm meaning to start using it in my next app (haven't yet).

`@temp = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT posts.id,posts.title, comment_count.count FROM posts INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments GROUP BY post_id) AS comment_count ON comment_count.post_id = posts.id  ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;")`

Could be (only a bit cleaner, but lets you chain scopes at least):

`@temp = Post.joins("JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments GROUP BY post_id) AS comment_count ON comment_count.post_id = posts.id").order("count desc").limit(5)`

I'm pretty sure `Arel` will let you do a sub-select a little more elegantly through scopes but I'm not familiar enough with it to give you a solution.

**EDIT**

You may be able to just add a `counter_cache` to your `comments` association on your `Post` model to avoid having to calculate it every time.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Docs from [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> :counter_cache
>
> Caches the number of belonging objects on the associate class through
>   the  use of increment_counter and decrement_counter. The counter cache
>   is incremented when an object of this class is created and decremented
>   when it’s destroyed. This requires that a column named
>   #{table_name}_count (such as comments_count for a belonging Comment
>   class) is used on the associate class (such as a Post class). You can
>   also specify a custom counter cache column by providing a column name
>   instead of a true/false value to this option (e.g., :counter_cache =>
>   :my_custom_counter.) Note: Specifying a counter cache will add it to
>   that model’s list of readonly attributes using attr_readonly.

Comment: Can you make the joins more simpler ?

Comment: You may be able to do so with `Arel`.  You may want to consider adding a `counter_cache` column on your `comments` association in your `Post` model.  See edit for other suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery here, you could simply say:

```
Post.select("posts.id, posts.title, COUNT(*) count").
     joins(:comments).
     group('posts.id').
     order('count DESC').
     limit(5)
```